# ¿Como generar múltiples class asignándole un nombre con un input?

Tags: python

Soy principiante en programación y estoy intentando crear una especie de banca personal trabajando solo con la consola de python.

Hace días que no encuentro una forma practica de hacer un generador de **múltiples** carteras

```
class entrada:

    def __init__(self, importe, descripcion):

        self.i = importe
        self.d = descripcion

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.i) + "\n" + str(self.d)

    def mostrar(self):
        print("Importe: ", self.i, "\n", "Descripcion: ", self.d)
```

Use esto como base y esta función creadora:

```
def creador_wallet():
    wallet(str(input("Selecione un nombre para su cuenta\n")), int(input("Ingrese un valor\n")))
```

(Probé embebiendolo en otro **`class`** pero no llegue a nada satisfactorio)

(Pensé en hacer un generador de ID random pero me pareció demasiado sofisticado)

Todo el sistema me funciona bien, mi problema es que quiero que se puedan crear mas de una wallet pero no se como poner un `input` antes del `= creador_wallet()`.

no se como hacer que se incruste el `input` asignado en el código posterior

```
input --> efectivo

input.mostrar()
```

????

Leí que se podía aplicar algo como **`raw_input`** pero estoy trabajando con Python 3.

Debe haber un algo que no estoy viendo o cometí un error al hacerlo objeto o debí hacer una biblioteca ( **`[importe, descripción]`** ) haciendo que el sistema auto complete el resto.

Acepto recomendaciones al respecto ya que ustedes sabrán que es mas práctico a largo plazo.

Comment: Revisa la indentación del código que has pegado, que no parece correcta. Mira aqui https://bit.ly/SOesPaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con instanciar la clase en una variable para que se guarde el input en el objeto al que esa variable referencia.

```
new = entrada(str(input("Selecione un nombre para su cuenta\n")), int(input("Ingrese un valor\n")))
new.mostrar()
```

Te debería dar:

```
Selecione un nombre para su cuenta
Cuenta1
Ingrese un valor
550
Importe:  Cuenta1
 Descripcion:  550
```

Y si quieres crear otra entrada, en lugar de `new`, le pones otro nombre. O si quieres manejar muchas, lo puedes hacer en una lista:

```
listaWallets = []
listaWallets.append(entrada(str(input("Selecione un nombre para su cuenta\n")), int(input("Ingrese un valor\n"))))
```

Y añades otro append, o lo puedes poner en un loop, si quieres más.